# jQuery arrays into cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

```
var adddata = [];
adddata[ group ] = [];
adddata[ group ][ id ] = option; // option is an object like { foo : 'bar' }

console.log( adddata ); // looks ok

$.cookie( 'cookiename', JSON.stringify( adddata ) );
console.log( $.cookie( 'cookiename' ) ); // just "[]"
$.cookie( 'cookiename', adddata );
console.log( $.cookie( 'cookiename' ) ); // "an empty string"

// in another file
var cdata = JSON.parse( $.cookie( 'cookiename' ) );
$.each( cdata, function( group, items ){
    /* and so on */
});
```

As you can see, I use the $.cookie plugin. But how can I store arrays into the cookie the right way?

Thanks & regards,
Alex

Comment: What does the result of JSON.stringify( adddata ) look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `group` and `id` are not numeric values, `JSON.stringify` will ignore them. Only numeric properties are taken  into account when converting an array to JSON.

See:

```
> a = []
  []
> a['foo'] = 5
  5
> a[0] = 42
  42
> JSON.stringify(a)
  "[42]"
```

You have to use an **object** `{}` if you deal with non-numerical properties:

```
> a = {}
  Object
> a['foo'] = 5
  5
> JSON.stringify(a)
  "{"foo":5}"
```

Never use a JavaScript **array** as associative array. JS arrays should only have numerical keys. For everything else, use plain objects.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is required before storage since a cookie can only be a string. However, there are JS/jQ cookie libraries available which attempt to transparently handle the un/serialization for you. The most popular cookie library which people use with jQuery (the one you are using) does not attempt to handle this for you, so your extra step is required.

**Edit:** Ah, I missed part of the question regarding the serialization not resulting in the correct value. See **Felix Kling**'s answer, it is correct.

Comment: thanks for your statement. I think `var encode = $.param(myObject);` is good for that. Decode with `var decode = decodeURIComponent(encode);`