# Jquery create/read associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following data

```
var field = fieldA|fieldB|fieldC
var values = 1|2|3
```

What I need to do is create an array like this:

```
fieldA:1 fieldB:2 fieldC:3
```

This will be set as a cookie using `JSON.stringify` and then I will `parseJSON` to get the values back in to an array.

I then need to be able to set these read this array back so i can set the fields to their correct values.

for example `fieldA`, `fieldB` and `fieldC` are all set to `0` on page load, I will read the cookie and set those fields to the values in the array;

```
fieldA = 1
fieldB = 2
fieldC = 3
```

Here is a code snippet of what I have so far. Cookie keeps saving as []

EDIT: Need to use Object since some of the values are are non numeric.  Changed arrayFinal = []; to arrayFinal = {};

```
Cookies.set("fields", JSON.stringify(builSearchString()));


function builSearchString() {
var fields = $('#advanced input').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get().join('|');
var values = $('#advanced input[type=text]').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get().join('|');
var array = fieldToValue(fields, values);
return array;


function fieldToValue(fields, values) {
var fieldArr = fields.split('|'),
    valueArr = values.split('|'),
    arrayFinal = [];
for (i = 0; i < fieldArr.length; i++)
    if (fieldArr[i] && valueArr[i])//validation
        arrayFinal[fieldArr[i]] = valueArr[i];
return arrayFinal;
}

 function getAdvancedSearchQuery() {
var cookie = Cookies.get("fields")
var array = $.parseJSON(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using a bitwise OR?

Comment: I think it's just meant as a field separator... :)

Comment: What about just making an object: `{"fieldA":1, "fieldB":2, "fieldC":3}`?

Comment: Spencer you are correct, had to use an object instead so it could be JSON.stringify correctly.  I changed arrayFinal = []; to arrayFinal = {} and now everything is working correctly.  Thanks to this link for the explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426033/jquery-arrays-into-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function solve it, try this:

```
function fieldToValue(fields,values){
    var fieldArr = fields.split('|'),
        valueArr = values.split('|'),
        arrayFinal = [];
    for (i = 0; i < fieldArr.length; i++)
        if(fieldArr[i] && valueArr[i])//validation
            arrayFinal[fieldArr[i]] = valueArr[i];
    return arrayFinal;
}
```

and call

```
fieldToValue("fieldA|fieldB|fieldC","1|2|3");
```

Comment: Ok i'm a little bit closer but now when i try and set it as a cookie, it sets it as [] (empty array) instead of JSON.stringify.  Any ideas?

Comment: Create the format string (JSON.stringify), and when you press and turn object (JSON.parse). Cookie stores only string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
var field = 'fieldA|fieldB|fieldC';
var values = '1|2|3';
var farr = field.split('|');
var varr = values.split('|');
var masterarr = [];
for (i = 0; i < farr.length; i++) {
  masterarr[farr[i]] = varr[i];
}
console.log(masterarr);
</script>
```